# Binomial proportion confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, python, proportion

I have a sample and I've classified each member into 3 groups A,B,C.

To get uncertainties on the percentages of these groups, I've been told I should use the [wilson score interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Wilson_score_interval). As someone who is not well versed in this area, I'm not really sure how to implement this in my code!

I've had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059011/is-there-any-python-function-library-for-calculate-binomial-confidence-intervals), but is an acceptable method for my case?

(I'm using python, so any hints in that area are very welcome!)

Comment: Three groups is not a binomial distribution.

Comment: @probabilityislogic When computing the standard error of the proportion in group $A$, the problem can be written in terms of "in group A" and "not in group A". As such, the standard error of the proportion when treating A-membership as binomial is actually the same as when you do the thing as a multinomial.

Comment: Lucidnonsense - you don't make it clear where your difficulty lies; which part of the formula is giving you implementation problems? It's a function of of $\hat p$, $z$ and $n$ - do you know how to find each? I'm pretty much ignorant of python, but at first glance it doesn't look like those are implementations of the Wilson score interval.

Comment: No that code is not an implementation of Wilson, but my difficulty lies in interpreting this formula. For instance it says that $\hat{p}$ is the normal distribution, $z$ is the $1 - \frac{1}{2}$ percentile of a standard normal distribution, $\alpha$ is the error percentile and n is the sample size.

How do I interpret this? Basically how do I use this formula and apply it?

Comment: @Glen_b - this is true only if you are interested in "A" vs "not A".  If you're interested in all three, then surely you should split the "not A" region into "B and not A" vs "C and not A".  The "CI" is a 2-D region here I would have thought.  Admittedly, the question is not clear on this.

Comment: @probabilityislogic I believe the aim is to calculate intervals for each of the individual population proportions.  Either way, I agree that the actual aim should be clearer, in that we should be told the problem rather than just some unknown person's solution to it, and be left to infer the underlying question from someone else's solution.

Comment: Lucidnonsense, please clarify the actual problem that is to be solved here. For example, are you trying to get an interval on each of the individual population proportions, or are you attempting to get some information about their joint uncertainty?

Comment: I'm trying to to get the  "A" vs "not A", as you put it, for each proportion (I assumed this was the only way to go about binomial proportion CIs, sorry for the confusion)

Comment: For the case of individual proportions like "A" vs "not A" statsmodels has the commonly used confidence intervals for proportions including Wilson http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportion_confint.html